# Why is there usually a six month time limit for bringing disability discrimination actions to court?

Tags: england-and-wales, discrimination, civil-procedure, statute-of-limitations

Kester Disability Rights note in a blog post of 25 Jun (page 6) that

> There is usually a six month time limit to get your case to court.

What provision might they be referring to and where can I read more about it?

Comment: The statement is repeated again on Feb 6 Nailing the Offenders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably refering to the time limit at [Section 118 of the *Equality Act 2010*](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/15/section/118). Subject to some exceptions,

> proceedings on a claim within section 114 may not be brought after the end of... the period of 6 months starting with the date of the act to which the claim relates ...

[Sonia Birdee (barrister)](https://www.gcnchambers.co.uk/barrister/sonia-birdee/) has shared some slides on the topic: [Limitation in Equality Act 2010 claims (non-employment)](https://dglegal.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/Discrimination-Common-Problems-%E2%80%93-Limitation-Webinar.pdf). She describes the general limitation period and also presents some ways of potentially getting more time.